# Why is the property last not declared in Swift Collection protocol?

Tags: swift, collections, foundation

Is there any reason in particular why the swift [collection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection) protocol does not provide a default implementation of the property `last`?

In other words, is there any reason why every type conforming to `Collection` has to reimplement the `last` property.

Comment: Determining the last element is a O(N) operation for general collections.   Compare https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/bidirectionalcollection: Bidirectional collections offer traversal backward from any valid index, not including a collection’s startIndex. Bidirectional collections can therefore offer additional operations, such as **a last property** that provides **efficient access** to the last element ...

Comment: Perhaps think the other way around: If your code needs (efficient) access to the last element then you might want to implement it for BidirectionalCollection (or RandomAccessCollection), instead of “reimplementing” that property.

Comment: Interesting, thank you @MartinR, never knew there was a `BidirectionalCollection`